# How to ask prettier to avoid new line with specific functions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

Prettier is awesome but it can be a handful sometimes. Consider the following piece of logic:

```
body("name")
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("Name is required")
    .isLength({ min: 3 })
    .withMessage("Name should be at least 3 characters long")
    .trim(),
```

This is nice but it's too long and it defeats the purpose of the intent of the API. I would like it to be:

```
body("name")
    .notEmpty().withMessage("Name is required")
    .isLength({ min: 3 }).withMessage("Name should be at least 3 characters long")
    .trim(),
```

Is there a way to confirm Prettier to have this very specific exception for `withMessage` API?